# Enable TYPO3 page content expiration date

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-tca

I'm in TYPO3 v.6.2 and from this year the expiration date is no longer accepting dates beyond 2020-12-31.

That was some sort of prophecy? XD

[image]

I suppose it is just a matter of configuration.

Where can I change that to enable future expiration dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the gentle reminder to upgrade your TYPO3 installation ;)

Your problem is that in old TYPO3 versions the upper limit of the date selector is hard coded in the TYPO3 core.

This can be fixed with a little bit of PHP code, e.g. in the `ext_localconf.php` or `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/YOUR_TABLE_NAME.php` of your own extension:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['YOUR_TABLE_NAME']['columns']['YOUR_FIELD_NAME']['config']['range']['upper'] =
    mktime(0,0,0,12, 31, 2030);
```

The code snippet must be adapted for every table and field that contains a date selector.

Comment: Thank you. The prophecy moved the end 10 years to the future. I hope I will be in a recent version.

The code:
`$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['endtime']['config']['range']['upper'] = mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 2030);`